# What is the ISubject and Operation() of the code in proxy design pattern?

Tags: java, proxy-pattern

I want to know base using the code below what is the:
1. ISubject and Operation()
2. realSubject: RealSubject and 
3. Operation()
    realSubject.Operation() 
on the UML diagram of Proxy design pattern

[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186001/Proxy-Design-Pattern)

```
//Payment.java
import java.math.*; import java.rmi.*;
public interface Payment extends Remote{
public void purchase(PaymentVO payInfo, BigDecimal price)
    throws PaymentException, RemoteException; }`

//PaymentProxy.java
import java.net.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.rmi.*;
      public class PaymentProxy implements PaymentService{
      private Payment implementation;
      private String serviceMachine = "localhost";
      private String serviceName = "paymentService";
      public PaymentProxy() throws ServiceUnavailableException{
          lookupRemoteService();
          }
private void lookupRemoteService() throws ServiceUnavailableException{
    try{
        String url = "//" + serviceMachine + "/" + serviceName;
        Object lookup = Naming.lookup(url);
            if (lookup instanceof Payment){
            implementation = (Payment)lookup;
    }
            else{
            throw new ServiceUnavailableException("Cannot locate remote service");
    }
    }
   catch (RemoteException exc){
   throw new ServiceUnavailableException("Error during remote service lookup", exc);
    }
    catch (NotBoundException exc){
    throw new ServiceUnavailableException("Remote service is not registered with naming server",     exc);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException exc){
    throw new ServiceUnavailableException("Malformed URL for naming lookup", exc);
    }
    }
      public void setServiceMachine(String machineName){
       serviceMachine = machineName;
    }
      public void setServiceName(String svcName){
       serviceName = svcName;
      }
       public void purchase(PaymentVO pay, BigDecimal price) throws PaymentException,     ServiceUnavailableException{
     try{
    if (implementation != null){
      implementation.purchase(pay, price);
     }
   }
   catch (RemoteException exc){
   try{
      lookupRemoteService();
       implementation.purchase(pay, price);
   }
    catch (RemoteException exc2){
     throw new PaymentException("Cannot process payment: remote communication problems with payment service", exc2);
     }
   }
  }
  }`

 //PaymentImpl.java
 import java.math.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.rmi.*;
 import java.rmi.server.*;
       public class PaymentImpl implements Payment{
       private static final String PAYMENT_SERVICE_NAME = "paymentService";

     public PaymentImpl() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException{
UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this);
Naming.rebind(PAYMENT_SERVICE_NAME, this);
}
public void purchase(PaymentVO payInfo, BigDecimal price)
  throws PaymentException{
}
}`
```

Comment: Please, fix the code. It's unreadable right now.

Comment: I'm new using stack. sorry

Comment: Where is ISubject/operation()? What exactly you need?

Answer (score 0):

The `PaymentProxy` should implement `Payment` instead of `PaymentService`:

```
public class PaymentProxy implements Payment {
```

In this case:

- `Payment` is `ISubject`;
- `PaymentImpl` is `RealSubject` (so `implementation` in `PaymentProxy` is the `realSubject` field);
- the overriden `purchase()` method corresponds to `Operation()` in `RealSubject`.

---

A more robust explanation:

The `Payment` interface is implemented by both classes. Additionally, each of them overrides the `purchase()` method. But the `PaymentProxy` is a **wrapper**, since it aggregates `PaymentImpl` and adds null checking in the overriden method:

```
  public void purchase(PaymentVO pay, BigDecimal price) throws PaymentException,       ServiceUnavailableException, RemoteException{
      if (implementation != null){
         implementation.purchase(pay, price);
      }
   }
```

Comment: I did not add the paymentService.java

Comment: import java.math.*;
public interface PaymentService{
    public void purchase(PaymentVO payInfo, BigDecimal price)
      throws PaymentException, ServiceUnavailableException;
}

Comment: If `PaymentProxy` implements an other iterface (`PaymentService` in this case) this is **NOT** a proxy pattern since `PaymentProxy` and `PaymentImp` may not be generalized to the same type.